# Update panels don't work after converting from VS 2005 to VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've updated to the latest version of the AjaxControlToolkit, but it still doesn't seem to work.  UpdatePanel for example works the first time, but it never hits my endrequesthandler.

Comment: Have you updated refference on AjaxControlToolkit dll in web-site's webReferences?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem. I have replaced scriptManager elements in the page with ToolKitScriptManager and it got working. ToolkitScriptManager can be found in ajax dll.  If you havent imported ajax dll upto now there is a step by step explanation here http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/06/ajax-control-toolkit-vsnet-2008.html

Hope it helps